# DataGridView in VB space between columns

Tags: vb.net

I have a problem using a DataGridView in Visual Studio.

This is the problem. There is no space between columns:

[image: This is the problem there is no space between columns]

I want to add space automatically between columns:

[image: I want to add space automatically between columns]

So, which property should I use?

Comment: `dataGridView1.Columns(0).HeaderText = "Customer ID"`

Answer (score 1):

defaultcellstyle.padding should do, here's an example:

Padding newPadding = new Padding(0, 1, 0, CUSTOM_CONTENT_HEIGHT);
this.dataGridView1.RowTemplate.DefaultCellStyle.Padding = newPadding;